# Make Javascript function ignores the last li to submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="ranges">
<ul>
<li>Op 1</li>
<li>Op 2</li>
<li>Op 3</li>
<li>Op 4</li>
<li>Op 5</li>
<li>Op 6</li>
<li>Op 7</li>
</ul>
```

I need to submit a form on the click of op 1, op 2, op 3, op 4, op 5, op 6. In other word, the last `li`, cant submit the form.
`In this the code Im trying to make this happen:

```
  gData.on('click', '.ranges ul li', function(e){
    gFilter.find('form').submit();
  });
```

But this `.ranges ul li`, will get all the `li`. How Can I make it ignore the last one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use combination of **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** and **[`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)**

```
gData.on('click', '.ranges ul li:not(:last)', function(e){
   gFilter.find('form').submit();
});
```

```js
$('body').on('click', '.ranges ul li:not(:last)', function(e){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ranges">
  <ul>
    <li>Op 1</li>
    <li>Op 2</li>
    <li>Op 3</li>
    <li>Op 4</li>
    <li>Op 5</li>
    <li>Op 6</li>
    <li>Op 7</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
  gData.on('click', '.ranges ul li:not(:last-child)', function(e){
    gFilter.find('form').submit();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:not(:last)`function in jQuery.

```
gData.on('click', '.ranges ul li:not(:last)', function(e){
gFilter.find('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
gData.on('click', '.ranges ul li', function(e){
    if ( !$(this).is(':last-child') ) {           //if this is not last child
        gFilter.find('form').submit();            //execute submit
    }
 });
```

Comment: Another good alternative to the answers already provided. Please note that computationally this answer is the slowest as of yet. (we are talking milliseconds though)

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add explanation to your code as it may not be clear to the OP as is.